# Filtering categoric and string/object values in pandas produces different results

Tags: python, pandas

Let's import a dataframe parsing some fields as 'categorical' type

```
import pandas as pd

dtypes = {
    "first_name": "category",
    "gender": "category",
    "type": "category",
    "state": "category",
    "party": "category",
}

df = pd.read_csv(
    "https://theunitedstates.io/congress-legislators/legislators-historical.csv", 
    dtype=dtypes,
    usecols=list(dtypes) + ["birthday", "last_name"],
    parse_dates=["birthday"]
)
```

When I do a query in these ones and then a groupby:

```
df.query("party in ["Democrat", "Republican"]).\
  groupby(["party", "state", "gender"]).\
  agg({"gender": "count"}).rename(columns={"gender": "counting"})
```

The dataframe outputs all the other values and not just 'Republican' and 'Democrat'.

When I don't parse these columns to categorical, I got my filtered result.

Why?

Comment: I can't tell you WHY, but this is the [documented](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/categorical.html#operations) behavior: `Groupby will also show “unused” categories`

Comment: But you can first do the groupby and than the query: `df.groupby(["party", "state", "gender"]).agg({"gender": "count"}).rename(columns={"gender": "counting"}).query('party in ["Democrat", "Republican"]')` --> yields 232 rows

Comment: I forgot to mention this "workaround", @Stef. Thanks. I'd really like to know why the pandas developers decided to keep unused categories. what's its advantages.